# Combining CodeIgniter 2 and Doctrine 2 | Setting up the proxy classes

Tags: php, codeigniter, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to get CI 2 and Doctrine 2 to work together, so far everything is going fine. However I now have a problem concerning the Proxy classes.

For some reason the proxy class is looking for a mapping file, which I don't have. Is this the normal behaviour?

The exception I get is:

```
'No mapping file found named 'proxies.modelsUserProxy.dcm.xml' for class 'proxies\modelsUserProxy'.'
```

Do I have to write mappings myself for the proxy classes? :/

I'll paste some of my code here:

```
// Proxy configuration
$config->setProxyDir(APPPATH.'proxies');
$config->setProxyNamespace('proxies');
$config->setAutoGenerateProxyClasses( TRUE );
```

The xml mapping in: *mappings/models.User.dcm.xml*

```
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping
                http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">

<entity name="models\User">
...
</entity>
```

Any information on this?

Comment: I'm using auto-generate proxy in my DOC2 Setup and having no issues with missing mapping files. Are you sure you set up your environment right? Are you referencing a model that doesn't exist? (and thus cannot generate a proxy?)

Comment: The models do exist, all the classes get generated correctly. Using the CLI I can also generate the proxies correctly. I have set up the autoloader to also load them so that shouldn't be the problem either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can find the answer on the following link (http://www.tlswebsolutions.com/codeigniter-2-and-doctrine-2-integration-a-working-setup-doctrineignited/) also, there's (http://wildlyinaccurate.com/integrating-doctrine-2-with-codeigniter-2/).

The first one, you can download a working Codeigniter2 + doctrine2.

Hope this helps ;)

Comment: Well I've got this problem too. And I've got the same settings in doctrine as the tutorials (but I work with xml mappings) and it keeps saying "No mapping file found".